# Cannot resolve symbol 'sqlite_sequence' and 'name in Android'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, androidx

I am facing this problem:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'sqlite_sequence'
>   Cannot resolve symbol 'name'

This problem occurred after migrating to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

[image: Room Database Problem]

Though app was running fine during debugging/dev, but when I tried to generate Signed APK, it caused this problem and it is not resolving.

Here is the result of **Analyze** >> **Inspect Code...**

[image]

Comment: Did you try "invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: I tried but didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

"sqlite_sequence" and "android_metadata" are not accessible within room database.

you have to use "SQLiteOpenHelper" to delete sequence.

Here is my code,

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String DATABASE_NAME = AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}


public static void resetAutoIncrement(DbHelper dbHelper,String tablename)
{
    dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='"+tablename+"';");
}}
```

use "resetAutoIncrement" method